# How to Rotate Shapes in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I have a shape in my C# code like an ellipse.  Now I want to programmatically rotate it.  For example, now I have a vertical ellipse and in the running I want to change it to a horizontal one.  How Is it possible?

Comment: WPF, Winforms? What tech are you using?

Comment: How are you representing that Ellipse in your code?

Comment: Without some information about how your ellipse is represented and/or how you're drawing it, it's impossible to say. Typically you use a transformation matrix to transform the shape or its individual points. But again, the form that matrix takes depends on your shape's representation. Without more information from you, we can't answer your question.

Comment: Thank guys . my code is C# for windows phone 8 . in windows phone programming I add using Microsoft.Expression.Shapes; then I use this code to add it in a Grid :

Comment: Ellipse btn = new Ellipse();    btn.width = 100;    btn.height = 100;   grid.children.add(btn);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved :

```
CompositeTransform co = new CompositeTransform();
                    co.Rotation = -90;
                    btn.RenderTransform = co;
```